# Problema com mysql workbeach

Tags: mysql

Estou com alguns bancos de dados funcionando normalmente , cro tabelas , procedures, e tudo mais normalmente. Tudo funciona.

Agora preciso importar uma modelagem de dados , então vou em file, open model , abro o meu modelo e quando o workbench vai carregar , aparece a mensagem de que o mysql parou de funcionar e o windows fecha o programa, me ajudem porque já pesquisei e nada achei sobre isso.

Comment: Cara não sei se essa pergunta se encaixa aqui pois o problema pode estar na instalação de seu mysql workbench, quem sabe reinstala ele ou pode ser em sua modelagem, fica meio complicado para o pessoal poder ajudar.

Comment: Tem como eu ver se existe algum erro na instalação? , Tipo por linhas de comando por exemplo?

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html